# Transfer information between states angularjs ui-sref, href

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a link that opens up a page:

```
<a href="#portfolio" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal"> </a>
```

This links to

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolio" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
            <div class="lr">
                <div class="rl">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    ...
```

which is currently just hardcoded data. When I move this out of the index.html page it ceases to work and I'm unsure why.

I have a way of transition between states using

`<a ui-sref="state2({keyId : key.id})">`

which already lets me take data from one link such as "key.id" or "portfolio.id" and move elsewhere.

I'm trying to make it so that when clicking the link provided by `<a href="#portfolio">` so that state2's data can be displayed using the portfolio id

Here's an example because this might be poorly explained. It obviously didn't work but hopefully gives an idea of what I am trying to do.

```
<a ui-sref="state2({keyId : key.id})" href="#portfolio" class="portfolio-link" data-toggle="modal">
```

Comment: Explain where modal is expected to show up. In current route or in new route (state2)? Expectations are a little fuzzy.Overall looks like a case for ripping out bootstrap.js and using angular-ui-bootstrap

Comment: @charliefl The modal is expected to show up when the link is clicked. The data passed from state2 is supposed to be displayed in the modal. I hope that made sense! Sorry, I didn't quite understand how it was supposed to work myself.

Comment: then you should definitely get rid of bootstrap.js and use angular-ui-bootstrap which has it's own controller for modal. Alternatively use a directive inside the modal and connect directive to a service that can get the data you need

Comment: @charliefl Is there a fairly easy to understand documentation that you could provide a quick link too?

Comment: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ FYI - same team that created UI router